# parsing command output on command line to use in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following command which get tomcat uid and gid

```
id tomcat
uid=91(tomcat) gid=91(tomcat) groups=91(tomcat),1002(java)
```

From the above command i need only uid and gid to assign to a seperate variable and to use in my code.

I have tried the following way which gives uid output

```
id tomcat | grep uid | awk '{print$1}'
uid=91(tomcat)
```

but i need only `91` --> which is uid of tomcat, so that i can use in my code.

Could you please suggest me how to achieve this, please forgive me for any mistakes.

Comment: `id -u tomcat` ?

Comment: Thanks oliv it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the commandline options of *id*

```
id -u
id -g
```

Comment: Thank you very much User2413548, it will be very easy for me now to include in my code, thanks once again :)